# Verilog: Are integer assignments slower than registers?

Tags: verilog, nonblocking, xilinx

I have this snippet:

```
n_rx                        <= 4;   // Integer (32 bits)
cpu_state                   <= 2;   // 2 Bit register                                       
helper_reg[4]               <= 1;   // 1 Bit register
```

These are non-blocking assignments, so I would think they would run in parallel and get values assigned at the same time, but this happens instead (ChipScope):

[image: Asynchronous non-blocking assignment.]

So evidently n_rx gets assigned later. [This document](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~jordicf/Teaching/secretsofhardware/VerilogIntroduction_Nyasulu.pdf) says that integers are implicitly treated as reg, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: Im not a bit fan of actually using integer type in synthesis (`reg [31:0]` or `logic [31:0]` is better), but that shouldnt be a huge issue. Did you do timing analysis in synthesis? It might be that you are running your design at a higher frequency than it can support due to its critical path.

Comment: `integer` is the equivalent to `reg signed [31:0]`. From what I read about ChipsScope, it appears to be a FSPA debug tool for post synthesis. So the delay can come from routing. There shouldn't be any delay in an RTL simulation. What is your clock period? Can you share your code?

Comment: @Greg, there is no delay in simulation, which is why it is a problem :( I can't post all of my code, but I can probably make some working snippet version of it. I did timing analysis for it when I synthesized it with ISE, but I'm pretty sure I never limited the frequency. So I'm going to install Vivado on my laptop (handing out candy currently) and check what that is set to.

Comment: IMHO, you can't say that integer assignments are slower? Why? Because it all depends on how your code was synthesised.

Comment: @Unn, my FPGA clock is 100MHz, the timing report says the worst slack is ~4ns, so I think my clock is ok?

Comment: @Qiu, How it was synthesized? With the Xilinx synthesis tool? I don't have much of a choice there and I didn't specify/change anything. The assignments look slow based on my code. I expect them all to happen at the same time, and they don't.

Comment: @Mewa: by "how" I meant: "what rtl structure was generated from you code".

Comment: @Greg, how much code would you like to see? It's a Vivado IP, so do you want me to post a link to a zip or something?

Comment: @Mewa, the minimums code we need to see is enough to show your coding style; such as your primary module / always block. If you can get your code to run on a simulator in [EDAplaygrond](http://www.edaplayground.com/) (or similar site), you can share the link to that and we will be able to see exactly what you are doing.